# How can I use the maven release plugin with a user that has @ in it?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins together with the release maven plugin.

My Jenkins job is a "maven" kind of job and is configured to :

1. git-clone the project with an identifier user@domain and access token
2. launch the following goals with Maven 3.8.3 :

   -B -X release:clean release:prepare release:perform

Below is the maven release plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Below is the section of the pom related to git repo:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <project.scm.id>gitlab</project.scm.id>
</properties>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://gitlab.some.domain/path/to/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@gitlab.some.domain/path/to/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://gitlab.some.domain/path/to/repo</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Here's the user settings file:

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab</id>
      <username>user@domain</username>
      <password>access token</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

When running the Jenkins job, the git clone part is fine. It uses the access token credentials provided in Jenkins setup : user@domain/**** (access token).

When it comes to the maven release plugin git-push operation, I receive an error while using the user settings file provided above:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.1:prepare (default-cli) on project xxx: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied, please try again.
[ERROR] Permission denied, please try again.
[ERROR] Received disconnect from 12.345.678.901 port 22:2:********@domain
[ERROR] Authentication failed.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Could this be due to the character @ in the user name ?

Answer (score 0):

I had left a SSH URL instead of HTTPS, so it was supposed to be :

```xml
<developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitlab.some.domain/path/to/repo.git</developerConnection>
```